# Vite proxy is fetching clientside files

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm trying to migrate my react project from webpack to vite and I'm facing this issue with proxies:

I've configured my proxy like so:

```
      port: 8000,
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:8080',
          changeOrigin: true,
        },
        '/graphql': {
          target: 'http://localhost:8080',
          changeOrigin: true,
        },
      },
    },
```

But if I use it like that, then vite starts requesting `localhost:8080/api` for clientside files like `localhost:8080/api/index.ts` which throws a MIME type error.

What’s the cause for this behavior and how can I fix it? The `http-proxy` documentation offers no details(which is what Vite uses)